# How to set default height to edittext view

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to apply 60dp height by default to all my entire app EditText view. Where did i make mistake?

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/custom_EditTextStyle</item>
    </style>

   <style name="custom_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittextbox</item>
        <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">4dp</item>
         <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You should post your AppBaseTheme style.

Comment: i already posted AppBaseTheme style. isnt that?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
<item name="android:layout_height">60dp</item>
```

Not

```
<item name="android:height">60dp</item>
```

Comment: When i removed android:layout_height from my edittext view - <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="username" />   my app is crashing?

Comment: Make sure you are applying the style to the EditText `<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="username" style="@style/custom_EditTextStyle" />`

Comment: Why should i add style again. We already added style to "AppBaseTheme". I feel once we added style in "AppBaseTheme" it will apply entire app with out adding style. what do you say?

Comment: Add `<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>` to the style and it will work

Comment: Added. But still crashing. updated code is -- <style name="custom_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittextbox</item>
       <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">60dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">4dp</item>
         <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    </style>

Comment: Make sure you have no layout_height or width set on your edittext as well. Set your edit text like this: <EditText android:text="username" />

Comment: Unfortunately, myApp has stopped.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31380/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-and-ken-wolf)